# Angular2+ component update after router.navigate()

Tags: angular

I have strange problem and I dont know how to solve it. I have my-offers.component thats shows announcements and form.component. When I use onOfferSubmit() it navigate's me to my-offers but do not shows new announcement added. I must to 'refresh' component using F5 or use navigate buttons that will start ngOnInit of my-offers.component. How to make it work?

form.component.ts

```js
onOfferSubmit(offerForm) {
  this.option === 'add' ? this.onAddOfferSubmit(offerForm.value) : this.onEditOfferSubmit(offerForm.value);
  this._router.navigate(['profile/my-offers']);
}
```

my-offers.component.ts

```js
export class MyOffersComponent implements OnInit {

myOffersId: string[];
privateLessons: PrivateLesson[] = [];

constructor(
  private _authService: AuthService,
  private _privateLessonsService: PrivateLessonsService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this._authService.getProfile().subscribe(
    profile => {
      this.myOffersId = profile.user.lessonsID;

      this.privateLessons = [];

      this.myOffersId.filter(offerID => {
        this._privateLessonsService.getPrivateLessonByID(offerID).subscribe(
          privateLesson => {
            this.privateLessons.push(privateLesson);
          }
        );
      });
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    }                  
  );
}
```

m-y-offers.component.html

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item"
      *ngFor="let privateLesson of privateLessons">
    <app-my-announcement [privateLesson]="privateLesson"></app-my-announcement>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit:

I'm navigating from http://localhost:4200/profile/add-offer to http://localhost:4200/profile/my-offers

Comment: do you call the same params again and again or is it like just a static router navigation

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the same route and only parameter values change You can try this -

You can inject the ActivatedRoute and subscribe to params

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.params.subscribe(val => {
    // put the code from `ngOnInit` here
  });
}
```

Comment: Route is changed, when form is submited

Comment: @lampkawtubce by route changed you mean ?

Comment: I mean url, and what you mean? :D

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz or something